# getting Error's while adding pallet_evm to runtime " the trait bound `pallet_evm::Pallet<Runtime>: Callable<Runtime>` is not satisfied in `Call`"

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, frontier, evm

I am trying  to add Evm pallet to my substrate runtime i am using **Polkadotv0.9.25** for both substrate and frontier but getting error  of  **trait bound** for almost every pallet.
error:-  **within `Call`, the trait `Callable<Runtime>` is not implemented for `pallet_evm::Pallet<Runtime>`** how to solve this error i have added evm to my runtime and also added its dependency in **cargo.toml**

[image]

Comment: Would you mind to provide the source-code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It usually means that you have dependency conflicts.

You can confirm which dependencies by looking for duplicated references in `Cargo.lock` file. To fix it, you need to update those dependencies to use the same version.

Sometimes you will have to use the [[patch]](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html#overriding-dependencies) section in the root `Cargo.toml` of your project to override those dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @Rodrigo